# R higher order function map on a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, higher-order-functions

In standard functional programming, `Map` takes a list `l` and a function `F` and returns a new list with `F` applied to every element. As an example consider:

```
F(x) = x^2 and the list l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`Map(f, l)` would produce the list: `[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]`

I would like to use this notion of `Map` on an R dataframe. I would like my function `F(x)` to compute `x / rowSum(row that x belongs to in the dataframe).`

Consider the data frame given by:

```
df <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:5)
{
  df <- rbind(df, c(i, i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4))
}
colnames(df) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

Which gives:

```
  a b c d e
1 1 2 3 4 5
2 2 3 4 5 6
3 3 4 5 6 7
4 4 5 6 7 8
5 5 6 7 8 9
```

I would like `Map(F, df)` to produce:

```
         [,1]      [,2] [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
v1 0.06666667 0.1333333  0.2 0.2666667 0.3333333
v2 0.10000000 0.1500000  0.2 0.2500000 0.3000000
v3 0.12000000 0.1600000  0.2 0.2400000 0.2800000
v4 0.13333333 0.1666667  0.2 0.2333333 0.2666667
v5 0.14285714 0.1714286  0.2 0.2285714 0.2571429
```

which is a dataframe where `F` is applied to every entry `x` in `df`.

The only hard part is figuring out how to write F:

```
F <- function(x) x / rowSum( row in which x belongs to in dataframe)
Map(F, df)
```

1. How do I write `F`

**EDIT** Here is an iterative solution:

```
pStat <- data.frame()
 for(i in 1: 5)
 {
   v <- df[i,] / rowSums(df[i,])
   pStates <- rbind(pStates, v)
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R's recycling rules work out of the box

```
df / rowSums(df)
```

A `data.frame` is a (column-oriented) list of equal-length vectors (try `df[[2]]`, for instance, or `str(df)`), so `Map(F, df)` is acting as in other functional languages by applying F to each column. The use of `rowSums` implies that the data are all numeric; it is often appropriate and efficient to then use a matrix, where recycling still works out of the box.

```
m <- as.matrix(df)
m / rowSums(m)
```

One could use a closure (e.g., a function that returns a function) to provide constant arguments (`rowSums(df)`) to a (inefficient) `Map` solution that acts explicitly on each column

```
Ffactory <- function(df) { r = rowSums(df); function(x) x / r }
mapped <- Map(Ffactory(df), df)
```

remembering to coerce the list to a data frame

```
as.data.frame(mapped)
```